# Telerik Mvc Chart Control Font Styling

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

Good day,

It's the first time I'm working with a Telerik MVC Chart control and I'm finding it difficult to change the chart's axes' default font. I searched the internet as much as I could but couldn't come up with a solution.

I'm testing on IE 9 at the moment.

I used Developer Tools to view the source and styles and what I picked up was that the chart is broken up into a div tag that contains an "svg" object. Inside the "svg" there are "text" objects for the items on the Y axis of the graph. Clicking on any "text" item and selecting "Style" in Developer Tools, reveals a section called "inline style". The font style is specified in the "inline style" section but I don't specify it in any of my CSS files in the project.

How can I change the font of those "text" entries of the "svg" by using a CSS class?

I must mention that I don't have any theme specified. The only telerik files included in my project are the "telerik.common.min.css", "telerik.default.min.css" and the Scripts folder containing the JS files.

Using ".HtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-family: Verdana; etc..." })" on the chart to set the font-family or other font related styles doesn't work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Inline styles mean that the styles are actually in the DOM on the elements tag.

You can't really target them in the external css unless you use the !important declaration after the style. (as far as I'm aware)

e.g.

```
element svg {
font-size:16px !important;
}
```